# Rabbit Admin Queue declaration using RabbitAdmin bean not working properly

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have queues and exchanges declared in my context-messaging files as follows:

```
<bean id="rabbitExchangeABCD" class="org.springframework.amqp.core.DirectExchange">
        <constructor-arg value="${EX_ABCD_ORDER}" />
</bean>

<bean id="rabbitDestinationABCD" class="org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue">
        <constructor-arg value="${QM_ABCD_ORDER}" />
</bean>
```

I am using the rabbitadmin bean to auto declare the queues using

```
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory"/>
```

I have more than 6 exchanges and 6 queues created like this but for one queue and exchange RabbitAdmin is adding unnecessary space at the end. As a result when I try to listen to that queue or bind that queue to any exchange (even in console) I get a 404 error saying queue not found.

I can verify the problem is with the space by doing the following:
In Logs
declaring Queue 'Q.XYZ.ABCD_MSG.CTM '
In console: http://auslabrmq01.us.dell.com:15672/#/queues/POC/Q.XYZ.ABCD_MSG.CTM%20

I made sure my properties file from where we are reading these properties have no space. Can someone explain this?

Comment: FYI: This is the first queue that is getting declared

Comment: There is no way that the admin wiil "add spaces at the end", so something else is going on; since the log clearly shows a space is there well before the admin gets it, try setting a breakpoint in the `Queue` constructor to figure it out. If you can reproduce it with a small sample app, edit your question and post it here.

Comment: Thanks Gary.. Will try that tomorrow.. 
There is an another problem where am I stuck, I posted a new question..can you guide?

Comment: Hi Gary, It turns out there was a space in my properties file only. I have a properties file which is reading values from another properties file(profiles).
The first properties file had a space. 
But do you think it is a good idea to handle whitespaces in RabbitAdmin itself?
Thanks for your prompt response!

Comment: I don't think the Admin can make any assumptions about what the user wants - RabbitMQ allows queues with spaces (as you have found).